# Proving that $\liminf (1/a_n) = 1/ \lim \sup (a_n)$ for any positive sequence $(a_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum, limsup-and-liminf

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $(a_n)$ be a positive sequence. Prove that
>   $$\dfrac {1}{\lim \sup a_n} = \lim \inf \left( \dfrac {1}{a_n} \right)$$
>   in the sense that if one side lies in $(0, \infty)$, then so does the other and the two sides are equal.

I am not really sure how to approach the last sentence.

Assuming everything exists, I believe that this problem comes down to showing that if $A$ is a set of positive numbers, then 
$$\inf \dfrac {1}{A} = \dfrac {1}{\sup A}$$

where $\frac{1}{A} = \left\{\frac{1}{a} \mid a \in A \right\}$.

I can prove that $\dfrac {1}{\sup A}$ is a lower bound for $1/A$, because for each $a \in A$ we have $a \le \sup A$, so $\frac 1a \ge \frac {1}{ \sup A}$. But I am having trouble proving that $\frac {1}{\sup A}$ is least among the upper bounds. I know that for $\epsilon > 0$, we have an $a \in A$ such that $\sup A - \epsilon < a \le \sup A$, but this turns into 
$$\dfrac {1}{\sup A - \epsilon} > a \ge \dfrac {1}{\sup A}$$
It makes sense that I can choose $\epsilon$ smaller and smaller and squeeze $a$ from above, but I don't know how to show it formally.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A \subseteq (0,\infty$) such that $\inf A>0$. Let $\frac{1}{A}=\{\frac{1}{a},a\in A\}$. Prove that $\sup \frac{1}{A}=\frac{1}{\inf A}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2087401/let-a-subseteq-0-infty-such-that-inf-a0-let-frac1a-frac1a)

Comment: Or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3369782/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the links. They help to answer the second part, unfortunately they don't seem to help with the last sentence of the problem, which I mentioned is causing issues.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "last sentence". The whole problem is two sentences, the first being 'let $(a_n)$ be a positive sequence'....? I also can't see what is left unclear by the links, if you still feel so can you edit your question to explain why?